# how to control the re-running with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a little bit of doubt in the useEffect function. I am trying to stop the unnecessary condition with useEffect. the question is can I control the useEffect with condition and is it possible?. the example code,

it is normal code,

```
useEffect(() => {
   // do something
},[variableName]);
```

my expectation code and question is,

```
useEffect(() => {
   // do something
},[variableName == 5]); // if it's true, Does the useEffect control the re-run?
```

it's like an if condition and is it possible to stop the re-run. I know it's weird but just for my clear understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? anyway `useEffect` is running _after_ render finished. Also there is no way _to stop render_. So better describe what do you believe that should help you with

Comment: you cannot `stop` a render, what do you want to achieve through this?

Comment: can I use the condition in the second parameter to control the re-run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can't. useEffect will be runned every time provided variable changed.

You have two options:

1. Stop function execution inside useeffect

```
    useEffect(() => {
       if (variableName!=5) return // do nothing if condition is not met
       // do something
    },[variableName]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set a boolian state in your functional component and set it to true if a certain condition is met and use that state variable as your second parameter for useEffect hook

Comment: can you give an example snippet code for clear understand?.